# Makefile how to generically chain on extra flags to target

Tags: bash, makefile

So I have a `test` target in a Makefile. What I want to do is allow an argument to be passed which allows invokers to chain on extra flags.

For the sake of this example, I will use grep instead of what I actually have since I can give an example anyone with UNIX can run vs requiring a complex set up to test.

My goal was to have a `make test` that will be the default test command but allow a `chain_in` argument such as `make test chain_on="-x"` which will run the default test command but append `-x` flag to the end. I had this working somewhat with the following solution:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

test: chain_on :=
test:
    echo bar | grep $$(if [ ! -z '${chain_on}' ]; then echo ' ${chain_on} '; fi)
```

Example usage `make foo chain_on='bar'`.

This works for simple flags like `-x`/`--foobar` or simple strings as above, but falls on its face when passing a flag with a quoted string argument.

For example `make foo chain_on='-I "bar"'` will run:

```bash
echo bar | grep $(if [ ! -z '-I "bar"' ]; then echo ' -I "bar" '; fi)
```

But that command results in an exit code 1...

`echo bar | grep -I "bar"` works fine though so something I have is messed up,.

I could run `make foo chain_on='-I bar'` but in my real use case I need the quotes because I have something like `'-k "foo or bar"'`.

Anyone know how to fix this or a round-about solution I can use to chain on extra arguments to a Makefile target?

---

**EDIT**: Actual example of what I have:

```
# SUPER - Run tests
# Arguments:
#   `chain_on=str` -> A string which will be appended to the end of the pytest command.
#       Ex: make test chain_on="-x"
tes%: chain_on :=
tes%:
    @poetry run python -m pytest \
        -o "testpaths=tests" \
        --cov=petlib \
        --cov-report term-missing:skip-covered \
        --cov-fail-under=100 \
        $$(if [ ! -z '${chain_on}' ]; then echo ' ${chain_on} '; fi)
```

WORKS: `make test`

WORKS: `make test chain_on="-x"`

WORKS: `make test chain_on="-k foo"`

DOESN'T WORK: `make test chain_on='-k "dumper or loader"'`

Comment: Again, why can't you just replace `$$(if [ ! -z '${chain_on}' ]; then echo ' ${chain_on} '; fi)` with simply `${chain_on}`?

Comment: TBH I used `${chain_on}` in my current makefile but the reason is the conditional adding of the extra space. I do not remember why it burned me but there was a point in time where I did just `foo ${chain_on}` and the space between `foo` and `${chain_on}` burned me when chain_on was empty so I switched to the ternary which made sure to only conditionally add the space. I wish I remembered what is was, maybe something if `IFS` but I do remember the pain of creating the ternary after that.

Comment: In this context it can't possibly matter whether there's a space there or not.  I mean, you already have a backslash/newline/tab before this, and a space before the backslash... there's all sorts of whitespace here.

Comment: I remember, the chain_on syntax I have actually came from `injection` in a different project. Something like `echo "foo ${injection} test"`, this would add an extra space in the echo vs the ternary would not. I just replicated to the chain_on since it was a safe copy and paste. So to answer you, with the context I provided, there was nothing wrong with your answer (which is why I upvoted and used it for this). But yeah, thats the reason, I just copy and paste the ternary since its safe to use anywhere within a target.

Comment: I recommend you work up a way to use the ternary via make constructs (e.g., the `$(if ...)` function) rather than shell constructs, and use that everywhere.  As you've seen, preserving correct quoting etc. is very tricky if you resort to `$$(if ...)` shell conditions.  It will work for simple situations but fail for more difficult ones.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that this week :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an extra shell level should help here :

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

tes%: chain_on :=
tes%:
    @bash -c "poetry run python -m pytest \
        -o 'testpaths=tests' \
        --cov=petlib \
        --cov-report term-missing:skip-covered \
        --cov-fail-under=100 \
        $$(if [ ! -z '${chain_on}' ]; then echo ' ${chain_on} '; fi)"
```

Test with :

```
make test chain_on='-k "dumper or loader"'
```

Comment: That works. It also makes it so I can pass env variables to the chain on properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't show really what you want to do it's a little hard to provide a solution we know will be acceptable.

I mean in your situation where all you want to do is replace a string if it's not empty, you could just use the variable.  Equivalent to what you've written above would be this:

```
test:
        echo bar | grep ${chain_on}
```

so presumably you need something more.  Providing an example which was much closer to your real requirements would be very helpful.

The problem you seem to face isn't really a make problem, it's a shell problem.  Passing a quoted string into a script then having it preserve its quoted attributes is a bit tricky to do in the shell.

Maybe do the testing using make functions instead of shell functions?  make doesn't care about quoting it just does plan string compares.  For example:

```
test:
    echo bar | grep $(if ${chain_on},${chain_on},)
```

(again of course as above this is a silly example).

Comment: I added an edit to show what I am actually doing in hope that the grep example make more sense with that.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I think this answer also work for the new edit too?

Comment: Sigh... Some days I really feel like an idiot. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Is there some issue with the obvious?

```
pytest_args ?=

tes%:
    @poetry run python -m pytest \
        -o "testpaths=tests" \
        --cov=petlib \
        --cov-report term-missing:skip-covered \
        --cov-fail-under=100 \
        $(pytest_args)
```

The caller should do all the necessary quoting, like this:

```
make testwhatever pytest_args='"two words"'
```

I.e. the caller must specify a `pytest_args` value that is a literal piece of shell syntax that can be dropped into the command line verbatim, with all necessary quoting.

Make does not deal very well (or at all, should we say) with argument material with spaces; don't try to construct quoted material inside a `Makefile`. Simple approaches will not be correct. For instance if you have `'${whatever}'`, that will fail if `whatever` itself contains the quote character.